# Will the movie "The Dead Sea" still be released?

Tags: production, casting, the-dead-sea

[Corey Haim](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000433/) is listed as the main character on the film [The Dead Sea](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1513927/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1). Corey died back in 2010 and I can't find any information about how much of the film finished before he passed away.

The film is listed on IMDb as being released next year.

How is it possible for them to finish a film after the actor has died? Is there any information released explaining what impact it had on the production of the movie?

Comment: `How is it possible for them to finish a film after the actor has died?` - See the `The Imaginarium of Doctor Parnassus`.  Or maybe `The Crow`.

Comment: @Zoredache nice examples.

Comment: @Zoredache want to expand that into an answer? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corey_Haim)

> He requested a "clean set" from producers to reduce temptation, though
>   his fellow cast members commented on his hyperactivity and need for
>   affection. Haim came to the set on his days off.

Looks like he doesn't worked in film for much time.

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1513927/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv),

> Though Corey Haim is listed in the credits, no footage of him was ever
>   captured on film or video. The credit is given in memory of.

That means we can conclude that his name is only included as a tribute. He doesn't have any footage in movie. His role might be cut of.

Answer (score 1):

Corey never filmed any scenes for the Dead Sea. They kept his character and name listed in tribute to him.

Comment: Please back up your claim with a source.